# Find all the points which satisfy $z^n = z$, where $z$ is a complex number. How many different solutions are there altogether?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Question:  Find all the points which satisfy $z^n = z$, where $z$ is a complex number, and $n$ is a whole number where $2 ≤ n ≤ 9$. How many different solutions are there altogether?

---

My attempt:

Usually with these root questions using complex numbers , I like to convert into polar form.

$$z^n = z$$

$$ z = r(cis(\theta)) $$

$$ z^n = r^n(cis(n\theta)) $$

$$ z = r^{n * \frac{1}{n}} (cis \frac{1}{n}(n\theta + 2\pi \times k)) $$

where k is any integer

$$ z = r^1 (cis (\theta+\frac{2\pi k}{n}))$$

If this is correct where do I go from here? Or if this is wrong please show me the correct way :)

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either  $z=0$ or $z \neq 0$, in which case you can divide by $z$ (note that $z=0$ is always a solution to the equation). If you divide the equation by $z$, you get $z^{n-1} = 1$ ; so the solutions are the $(n-1)^{\text{th}}$ roots of units. Therefore your solution set for a fixed $n$ is
$$
 \{0 \} \cup \{ e^{2\pi i k/(n-1)}, k \in \{0,\cdots,n-2\} \}. 
$$
Afterwards you look at all your solutions and look at the distinct ones ; in other words, you need to check if a solution to $z^3=z$ is not a solution to $z^9=z$ for instance. But if $z^3 = z$, then
$$
z^9 = (z^3)^3 = z^3 = z
$$
so you can remove these cases in your counting.

P.S. : If you converted to polar form, you would have to divide by $z$ eventually to solve for the radius and angle anyway. This is the only reasonable way to proceed.

Hope that helps,